# Pivot and manipulate data for old vs new in r

Tags: r

I have the following two data frames:

```
dates <- c("2021-01-01","2021-02-01","2021-03-01","2021-04-01","2021-01-01","2021-02-01","2021-01-01","2021-01-01","2021-02-01","2021-03-01","2021-04-01","2021-02-01","2021-03-01","2021-04-01","2021-03-01","2021-04-01","2021-03-01","2021-04-01")
dates <- as.Date(dates)
category <- c("A","A","A","A","B","B","C","D","D","D","D","E","E","E","R","R","S","S")
sales <- c(12,8,12,2, 10,9,5,2,3,22,17,2,14,12,20,23,21,25)

df1 <- data.frame(dates,category,sales)
old <- c("C",'A',"B")
new <- c("E","R","S")

df2 <- data.frame(old,new)
```

I want two create two separate data frames where the columns are Months and Rows are the values of each category

[image]

and the last data frame that divides New by Old

[image]

If the result is nan replace it by 100.

Comment: R/A; Month-4 for A: 2 ; Month-4 of R: 23; R/A for Month-4 = 23/2 = 11.5

Comment: Please check the updated solution

Comment: @akrun is there a way to change the division new/(old+new)

Comment: For that you may need to change the denominator with `.[match(df2$old, category, nomatch = 0)] + .[match(df2$new, category, nomatch = 0)]`

Comment: `summarise(New_Old = str_c(df2$new, df2$old, sep="/"), across(starts_with('Month'), 
      ~ .[match( df2$new, category, nomatch = 0)]/
          (rowSums(cbind(.[match(df2$old, category, nomatch = 0)], .[match( df2$new, category, nomatch = 0)]), na.rm= TRUE))))` in that code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a 'Month' column from `format`ing the 'dates' column and use `pivot_wider` to reshape from 'long' to 'wide' format

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
     mutate(Month = format(dates, 'Month%m')) %>% 
     select(-dates) %>% 
     pivot_wider(names_from = Month, values_from = sales, values_fill = 0)
```

---

For the second case, after the reshaping, keep only the rows where there is a 'category' found in either 'old' or 'new' column from 'df2' (`filter`), then use `summarise` to `match` the 'category' with the corresponding 'new', 'old' columns by looping `across` the 'Month' column, and subset the elements of the column and divide

```
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
     mutate(Month = format(dates, 'Month%m')) %>% 
     select(-dates) %>% 
     pivot_wider(names_from = Month, values_from = sales, values_fill = 0) %>%
     filter(category %in% unlist(df2)) %>% 
     summarise(New_Old = str_c(df2$new, df2$old, sep="/"), across(starts_with('Month'), 
      ~ .[match( df2$new, category, nomatch = 0)]/
          .[match(df2$old, category, nomatch = 0)]))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 5
  New_Old Month01 Month02 Month03 Month04
  <chr>     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 E/C           0     Inf  Inf      Inf  
2 R/A           0       0    1.67    11.5
3 S/B           0       0  Inf      Inf
```

Comment: This is the solution for initial screenshot The problem I had was with the final df that needs to be created. How do I  use df2 dynamically to create the final result